# Drupal 7 Commerce Frontpage VIEW does not show products

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, commerce

I got the following problem. As a logged in user and administrator I'm able to see the view, but as anonymous user the view with products inside has disappeared.

In the view I got no permissions set and on the admin/people/permissions everything is normal. Does anybody know where I'm failing?

Here is my export of the VIEW:

```
    $view = new view();
$view->name = 'frontpage';
$view->description = 'Emulates the default Drupal front page; you may set the default home page path to this view to make it your front page.';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Front page';
$view->core = 0;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '8';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['quantity'] = '9';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grid';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Content: Referenced products */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_product_product_id']['id'] = 'field_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_product_product_id']['table'] = 'field_data_field_product';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_product_product_id']['field'] = 'field_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['field_product_product_id']['label'] = 'Products';
/* Field: Commerce Product: Images */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['id'] = 'field_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['table'] = 'field_data_field_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['field'] = 'field_images';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['relationship'] = 'field_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['element_type'] = 'div';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => 'medium',
  'image_link' => '',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['delta_offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_images']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Field: Commerce Product: Price */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['id'] = 'commerce_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['table'] = 'field_data_commerce_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['field'] = 'commerce_price';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['relationship'] = 'field_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_wrapper_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['click_sort_column'] = 'amount';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['settings'] = array(
  'calculation' => '0',
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['commerce_price']['field_api_classes'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Commerce Product: Add to Cart form */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['id'] = 'add_to_cart_form';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['table'] = 'views_entity_commerce_product';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['field'] = 'add_to_cart_form';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['relationship'] = 'field_product_product_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['show_quantity'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['default_quantity'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['combine'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['display_path'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['add_to_cart_form']['line_item_type'] = 'product';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Sticky */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['id'] = 'sticky';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['field'] = 'sticky';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'product_display' => 'product_display',
);
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['group'] = 1;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Promoted to front page */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['promote']['id'] = 'promote';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['promote']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['promote']['field'] = 'promote';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['promote']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['promote']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['promote']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'frontpage';

/* Display: Feed */
$handler = $view->new_display('feed', 'Feed', 'feed');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Front page feed';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'rss';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node_rss';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'rss.xml';
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'default' => 'default',
  'page' => 'page',
);
$handler->display->display_options['sitename_title'] = '1';
$translatables['frontpage'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('Products'),
  t('Title'),
  t('Page'),
  t('Feed'),
  t('Front page feed'),
);
```

Comment: Try removing filter options one by one (i.e. first clone the view and work with the copy) to see will the products appear eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue on a site I developed in the past. Drupal Commerce seems to be fussy when it comes to permissions.

I know of two routes you can follow to resolve this:

1. Edit your view. Under "Advanced", select "Query Settings", and tick "Disable SQL rewriting". Only do this if the view doesn't display sensitive information. Make sure you add a filter that checks to see if "Commerce Product: Status" is true, or you'll display unpublished products
2. Give the Anonymous user the "View any product of any type" permission.

Comment: your number 1 worked out for me. I didn't expect that this little thing can cost me so mutch effort. :) thank you for helping

Comment: Glad it helped!